# ASMX STRING[] to client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx, aspxgridview

First of all , it's my fist time working with asmx.
So basically i have multiple services list<string> , that returns as string[] in the front, my question is can we bind those  services in one datatable on the client-side ? should i pass by a Layer o a class to make it easier ?

I tried this :

```
string[] Service1= client.Getlist1(NumAbonne.Text).ToArray();
string[] Service2= client.Getlist2(NumAbonne.Text).ToArray();
.............................................................
.............................................................
string[] Service5 = client.Getlist5(NumAbonne.Text).ToArray();
.

 List<string> list = new List<string>(Service);
 List<string> list1 = new List<string>(Service2);
.............................................................
.............................................................
 List<string> list4 = new List<string>(Service5);
```

and i displayed each one of them , in a row , but i feel like there is a simpliest way to do this, does someone have another approach ?

[exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0lLN.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I think we need a little bit more context. Does each array (service1, service2,... serviceN) have the same length? If you want to store each array as a row in a DataTable, I imagine each element of the array will be stored in its own column.

Comment: no they don't have the same lenght , actually for each data in the service1 i want to display all the data of the other services each one in a row something like the picture i put on the post "exemple"

Comment: Ok but I still don't understand exactly the correlation between the services. 
So basically if GetList1() returns an array with 3 string elements [str_11, str_12, str_13]. 
And GetList2 returns [str_21, str_22] and GetList3 returns [str_31, str_32, str_33, str_34], you want to display a table like this ? row1: [str_11, str_21, str_22], row2: [str_11, str_31, str_32, str_34], row3: [str_12, str_21, str_22], row4: [str_12, str_31, str_32, str_33, str_34], row5: [str_13, str_21, str_22], row5: [str_13, str_31, str_32, str_33, str_34] ?

Comment: Yeah something like that